# Open File in a Sharepoint list via VBA

Tags: excel, vba

I want to open an excel file in a Sharepoint list via VBA. Here is my code:

```
Sub OpenWB()

Dim SummaryWB As Workbook
Dim vrtSelectedItem As Variant

With Application.FileDialog(msoFileDialogOpen)
.InitialFileName = "https://sharepoint.com/teams/sdeteam/Shared Documents/folder/ALM Automated Transfer/" & "\"
.AllowMultiSelect = False
.Show
For Each vrtSelectedItem In .SelectedItems
    Set SummaryWB = Workbooks.Open("Financial Trackerv8.xlsx")
Next
End With

If SummaryWB Is Nothing Then Exit Sub

End Sub
```

It only opens the folder but not the file. What's supposed to be wrong with my code?

Answer (score 1):

From my experience you are not able to directly open a file on SharePoint like that.  You need to download the file first and then open it.  I store the file in the user's temp folder via the code below, and if necessary delete it upon closing.

```
Sub DownloadSPfile()
Dim strFolder As String
Dim strName As String
Dim URL As String 

strFolder = Environ("temp")
strName = "\DART_db.accdb"
URL = <file location>

If Dir(strFolder & strName) <> "" Then ' if the temp file already exists then delete it first
      VBA.SetAttr strFolder & strName, vbNormal ' remove any file attributes (e.g. read-only) that would block the kill command
      VBA.Kill strFolder & strName ' delete the file
End If

FileCopy URL, strFolder & strName

End Sub
```

Answer (score 1):

You can open a SharePoint file directly using VBA without having to save it to a temp folder.  I use this code to open Email Templates with VBA that are stored on SharePoint, but you can modify it to open other files types as needed.

```
Sub SendIntEmail1()

Dim OutApp
Dim OutMail As Outlook.MailItem
Dim IVMmail, IntAttach As String

Sheets("Macro Run Controls").Select

IntAttach = Folder path to files I attach
IVMmail = \\SharePoint Site\Path to Email Templates\Email Template.oft

'Create the external manager email
If IntMgrStr <> "" Then
Set OutApp = CreateObject("Outlook.Application")

On Error Resume Next

Set OutMail = OutApp.CreateItemFromTemplate(IVMmail)
With OutMail
    .SentOnBehalfOfName = "TeamEmail@mail.com"
    .To = ""
    .CC = ""
    .BCC = IntMgrStr

    StrFile = Dir(IntAttach & "*.*")
    Do While Len(StrFile) > 0
        .Attachments.Add IntAttach & StrFile
        StrFile = Dir
    Loop

    .Display   'or use .Send
End With

On Error GoTo 0
End If
```